# Page 404 error in Password reset confirm in django 2.2.8

Tags: python, django, authentication

[image]

Dear All I am trying to create a password reset for my django project. Everything works including the email that is sent and the link where I enter a new password but I get the error as shown in screenshot as I click submit on my password_reset_confirm view. I am a complete beginner.

Here are my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import path, reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from accounts.views import login, register, logout
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetView
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', login, name='login'),
    path('register/', register, name='register'),
    path('logout/',  logout, name='logout'),
    path('password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='accounts/password_reset_form.html'), name='password_reset'),
    path('password-reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='accounts/password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='accounts/password_reset_confirm.html'), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password-reset-complete/',  auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='accounts/password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_reset_complete')

]
```

my main urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('home.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem was in my password_reset_confirm.html. I had remove the submit value on my form and change to only method=="POST".